# Update column in table depending on table data

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am working on a table on SQL where I need to fill in a new column depending on the value of 2 other columns in the table.

The rules are:
 - New column = 1 if Row id = 1 and the group id for that row has more rows with the same group id (See pic)
 - New column = 2 if Row id >= 2
 - Anything else will make the new column 0

Table
[image]

This is my query to update the new column which works:

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.New_Column = CASE WHEN t1.RowID >= 2 THEN 2 
                                    ELSE CASE WHEN t1.RowID = 1 and (SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.__test1 as t2 WHERE t2.GroupID = t1.GroupID) > 1 
                                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END   from dbo.__test1 as t1
```

The end table result(Correct):
[image]

I want to know if there is a better and more efficient way of updating the new column as I feel calling the table within the select to count the number of group id's doesn't seem right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will be faster to get the counts at the table level instead of row.

Removed one level of your `CASE` expression too - that probably won't change anything but it's a little cleaner to my eyes.

```
UPDATE t
SET t.NewColumn = CASE WHEN t2.RowID >=2 THEN 2
                       WHEN t2.RowID = 1 AND cnt > 1 THEN 1
                       ELSE 0 
                       END
FROM dbo.__test1 t
JOIN (SELECT GroupID, COUNT(*) cnt
      FROM dbo.__test1
      GROUP BY GroupID) t2 on t.GroupID = t2.GroupID
```